# How to close inflated layout?

Tags: java, android

I inflate layout with  `TYPE_SYSTEM_ALERT` and `FLAG_LAYOUT_IN_SCREEN`

```
 params = new WindowManager.LayoutParams(
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_SYSTEM_ALERT ,
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_LAYOUT_IN_SCREEN,
            Color.YELLOW);

    wm = (WindowManager) getApplicationContext()
            .getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE);

    mTopView = (ViewGroup) getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.lock_screen, null);
    getWindow().setAttributes(params);
    wm.addView(mTopView, params);
```

How can I close or dismiss it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remove your view using below code when needed

```
if(mTopView!=null) {
   wm.removeView(mTopView);
}
```